# Find the length of longest substring in a big string

Tags: string, algorithm

I have the following problem, let's say we have given string N, such that the length of string N can go up to 250000.

Now in this string we have to find the length of longest substring that has the form XYXY, where X is part of the substring and Y is reversed version of X, here are couple examples

N=PERREERREERREABC, P**ER RE ER RE**ERREABC, here X=ER, Y=RE, and the answer here is 12.

N=AAAA, **A A A A** X=A, Y=A, so the answer is 4

N=ABCDDCBAFE, here we have substring of the form XY but we need to count only if there is substring of the form XYXY, so the answer in this case is 0.

I coded bruteforce solution for this but that is too slow for the time limit, how can i improve it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why is the answer for "ERREERREERREABC" 12? According to your explanation, X and Y are each two characters long in that example so XYXY would be only 8 characters.

Comment: There is mistake in my explanation the answer is 8

Comment: @someone12321 you should edit your post then! Also consider sharing the code.

Answer (score 0):

I Think you could use the stack for better solution, you push a character into the stack if and only if it's not equal to the character at the top of the stack and you pop otherwise.

When you use pop() operation you could store some string to guarantee XYXY

Answer (score 0):

I guess the given problem is a variation of the standard 'Longest palindrome' dynamic programming problem. You can find a detailed discussion and implementation [here](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dynamic-programming-set-12-longest-palindromic-subsequence/).

The variation is after finding the palindrome apply the 2 checks.

1. Even length
2. XYXY format

Comment: Even length is not the only variation. He's looking for a specific type of palindrome. See his example of "ABCDDCBAFE." Although "ABCDDCBA" is a palindrome, it doesn't qualify. So first you have to find the palindrome, and then you have to determine if it's the right type.

Comment: @jim mischel, thanks for pointing. Modified the answer accordingly.